# Sharing a custom field across multiple team projects in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have a TFS 2010 installation with several Team Projects.  Is there a good way to use the same field name across multiple Team Projects?

At current, when I try to add the field "Requested By" to the user store work item in one team project, I get the error:

> TFS237094 : Field Name 'Requested By is used by the field
>   'SomeOtherTeamProject.RequestedBy' so it cannot be used by the field
>   'ThisTeamProject.RequestedBy'.

Update
Based on discussion, this appears to be due to my trying to add a field with same Name but different Reference Name.

Comment: How are you adding the field? What the the Field Definitions?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm using TFS Power Tools. (Tools | Process Editor | Work Item Types | Open WIT from Server)

Comment: Does each Field have the same name and different refnames per chance?

Comment: Yes. Ah... so if those match, I don't get the error. Now the error makes sense. If you want to answer this, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating Fields in TFS the "Name" and "RefName" have to be unique. Re-using a field "Name" with a different "RefName" is not allowed.

The common practice for custom fields is to use the RefName as `Company.FieldName` as opposed to the Team Project Name.

By default any new field you add is available to all Team Projects in the Collection to use.